# Determine the irreducibility of a polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

For a positive integer $n$, is the polynomial $f_n(x)=x^{n-1}+\dots+x+1$

1. irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ for every $n$?
2. irreducible for every prime $p$?
3. irreducible for $p^n$ for all prime $p$ and positive integer $n$?
4. $f_p(x^{p^{n-1}})$ is ireducible for all prime $p$ and  positive integer $n$?

I don't know how to prove or disprove the above statements. Please help.

Comment: It is instructive to realize that $(x-1)f_n(x)=x^n-1$. That lets you "see" what the roots of $f_n(x)$ are, but also to find other factors of $f_n(x)$ because $x^n-1$ has "obvious" factors other than $x-1$ in many cases.

Comment: It would be helpful to us to know what you know. For example, one answer mentions Eisenstein's Criterion. Have you covered that?

Answer (score 7):

As to (4), it has been discussed here recently. When $p$ is prime, $f_{p}(x) = \Phi_{p}(x)$ is the $p$-th [cyclotomic polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial).

Now the $p^{n}$-th cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_{p^{n}}(x)$ (where $p$ is prime) is monic, of degree $\varphi(p^{n}) = (p-1) p^{n-1}$, and is irreducible in $\Bbb{Q}[x]$. It is the minimal polynomial over $\Bbb{Q}$ of a primitive $p^{n}$-th root of unity.

If $\alpha$ is a primitive $p^{n}$-th root of unity, then $\alpha^{p^{n-1}}$ is a primitive $p$-th root of unity, and so it is a root of $f_{p}(x)$. Thus $\alpha$ is a root of $g(x) = f_{p}(x^{p^{n-1}})$.

Now $g(x)$ is monic, of degree $(p-1) p^{n-1}$, and has $\alpha$ as a root. It follows that $g(x) = f_{p}(x^{p^{n-1}}) = \Phi_{p^{n}}(x)$, and thus $g(x)$ is irreducible in $\Bbb{Q}[x]$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

The first statement is false, take $n=4$ as counterexample.

For the second one, substitute $x=y+1$, expand it, and use Eisenstein Criterion.

The third statement is also false as $4=2^2$.